# How to run a program by default app in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to start my app with python by defalut. Like double-clicking on them.

I know there is `subprocess.Popen("program", "file")` but I need to start app by default and I don't know with what `program` I need to start app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for windows you can use `os.startfile(FILEPATH)`
and for macOS you can use `subprocess.call(('open', FILEPATH))`

and for all systems this code is useful:

```
import platform
import os

if platform.system() == 'Darwin':       # macOS
    subprocess.call(('open', FILEPATH))
elif platform.system() == 'Windows':    # Windows
    os.startfile(FILEPATH)
else:                                   # linux variants
    subprocess.call(('xdg-open', FILEPATH))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `subprocess.call(['name-of-file'])`

Comment: On windows, `subprocess.call(["log.txt"])` throws an `OSError`